# C++ prioritize data synchronization between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a scenario, where I have a shared data model between several threads. Some threads are going to write to that data model cyclically and other threads are reading from that data model cyclically. But it is guaranteed that writer threads are only writing and reader threads are only reading.

[image]

Now the scenario is, that reading data shall have higher priority than writing data due to real time constraints on the reader side. So it is not acceptable that e.g. a writer is locking the data for a too long time. But a lock with a guaranteed locking time would be acceptable (e.g. it would be acceptable for the reader to wait max 1 ms until the data is synchronized and available).

So I'm wondering how this is achievable, because the "traditional" locking mechanisms (e.g. `std::lock`) wouldn't give those real time guarantees.

Comment: Seems like the wrong focus. The writing thread has to hold the lock as long as it's writing. If the application needs to release the lock it has to ensure that the writing thread stops writing. So that's where the time management should come in: stop the writer, and then use the normal mechanism to release the lock.

Comment: `So it is not acceptable that e.g. a writer is locking the data for a too long time.` If it is indeed only for the time the writers lock data then it is responsibility of the writers to release the lock in time. A forceful revoke of the lock from a writer might lead to inconsistent data, which might have even worse impacts than not hitting real time conditions!

Comment: Or are you after shared locks, i.e. the readers should be able to read in parallel? Then the problem might indeed arise when readers are enqueued after a writer that first needs to wait for the previous readers to complete while the new one needs to wait for the writer (even if that one only locks sufficiently short). But if you start to post-pone the writers, how are you avoiding them finally starving under bad circumstances?

Comment: I think that the pattern you're looking for is multipe-readers, single-writer lock. Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex with which you can do this.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Possibly, but not necessarily. If a writer indeed holds a lock for too long then the issue still is not solved...

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for some (software) transactional memory? That's the only way to have readers truely independent of writers (and vice versa), although there's a price to pay: speed (typically not worse than 2x) and space.

Comment: 1ms is a really long time if you are talking about a modern PC.  A mutex might not be deterministic, but it will be so much faster than 1ms that you are prematurely optimizing something that will probably never be a bottleneck, unless your writer is writing much more often than you are reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to have two identical copies of the dataset; call them copy A and copy B.

Readers always read from copy B, being careful to lock a reader/writer lock in read-only mode before accessing it.

When a writer-thread wants to update the dataset, it locks copy A (using a regular mutex) and updates it.  The writer-thread can take as long as it likes to do this, because no readers are using copy A.

When the writer-thread is done updating copy A, it locks the reader/writer lock (in exclusive/writer-lock mode) and swaps dataset A with dataset B.  (This swap should be done by exchanging pointers, and is therefore O(1) fast).

The writer-thread then unlocks the reader/writer-lock (so that any waiting reader-threads can now access the updated data-set), and then updates the other data-set the same way it updated the first data-set.  This can also take as long as the writer-thread likes, since no reader-threads are waiting on this dataset anymore.

Finally the writer-thread unlocks the regular mutex, and we're done.

Answer (score 2):

Normally in such a scenario you use a [reader-writer-lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock). This allows either a read by all readers in parallel or a write by a single writer.

But that does nothing to stop a writer from holding the lock for minutes if it so desires. Forcing the writer out of the lock is probably also not a good idea. The object is probably in some inconsistent state mid changed.

There is another synchronization method called [read-copy-update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update) that might help. This allows writers to modify element without being blocked by readers. The drawback is that you might get some readers still reading the old data and others reading the new data for some time.

It also might be problematic with multiple writers if they try to change the same member. The slower writer might have computed all the needed updates only to notice some other thread changes the object. It then has to start over wasting all the time it already spend.

Note: copying the element can be done in constant time, certainly under 1ms. So you can guarantee readers are never blocked for long. By releasing the write lock first you guarantee readers to read between any 2 writes, assuming the RW lock is designed with the same principle.

---

So I would suggest another solution I call write-intent-locking:

You start with a RW lock but add a lock to handle write-intent. Any writer can acquire the write-intent lock at any time, but only one of them, it's exclusive. Once a write holds the write-intent lock it copies the element
and starts modifying the copy. It can take as long as it wants to do that as it's not blocking any readers. It does block other writers though.

When all the modifications are done the writer acquires the write lock and then quickly copies, moves or replaces the element with the prepared copy. It then releases the write and write-intent lock, unblocking both the readers and writers that want to access the same element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful to me. Unfortunately I can "accept" only one answer even though all of the answers are very helpful to find a concrete solution for my problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've got readers, and you've got writers, and you need a lock, so.... how about [a readers/writer lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)?

The reason I mention that up-front is because (a) you might not be aware of it, but more importantly (b) there's no standard RW lock in C++ (EDIT: my mistake, one was added in C++14), so your thinking about this is perhaps being done in the context of std::mutex. Once you've decided to go with a RW lock, you can benefit from other people's thinking about those locks.

In particular, there's a number of different options for prioritizing threads contending over RW locks. With one option, a thread acquiring a write lock waits until all current reader threads drop the lock, but readers who start waiting after the writer don't get the lock until the writer's done with it.

With that strategy, as long as the writer thread releases and reacquires the lock after each transaction, and as long as the writer completes each transaction within your 1 ms target, readers don't starve.

And if your writer *can't* promise that, then there is zero alternative but to redesign the writer: either doing more processing *before* acquiring the lock, or splitting a transaction into multiple pieces where it's safe to drop the lock between each.

If, on the other hand, your writer's transactions take *much less* than 1 ms, then you might *consider* skipping the release/reacquire between each one if less than 1 ms has elapsed (purely to reduce the processing overhead of doing so).... but I wouldn't advise it. Adding complexity and special cases and (shudder) *wall clock time* to your implementation is rarely the most practical way to maximize performance, and rapidly increases the risk of bugs. A simple multithreading system is a reliable multithreading system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful to me. Unfortunately I can "accept" only one answer even though all of the answers are very helpful to find a concrete solution for my problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

If model allows writing to be interrupted, then it also allows buffering. Use a fifo queue and start reading only when there are 50 elements written already. Use (smart)pointers to swap data in fifo queue. Swapping 8 bytes of pointer takes nanoseconds. Since there is buffering, writing will be on a different element than readers are working with so there wont be lock contention as long as producer can keep the pace with producers.

---

Why doesn't the reader produce its own consumer data? If you can have n producers and n consumers, each consumer can produce its own data too, without any producer. But this will have different multithread scaling. Maybe your algorithm is not applicable here but if it is, it would be more like independent multi-processing instead of multi-threading.

---

Writer work can be converted to multiple smaller jobs? Progress within writer can be reported to an atomic counter. When a reader has a waiting budget, it checks atomic value and if it looks slow, it can use same atomic value to instantly push it to 100% progress and writer sees it and early-quits lock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful to me. Unfortunately I can "accept" only one answer even though all of the answers are very helpful to find a concrete solution for my problem at hand.